# how to append based on object key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this :

```
Object 
    section : array (1)
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'foo'}

    unit : array(2)
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'bar'}
    1 : {id : 2, name: 'bar2'}
```

but how to detect if the object has a section key or not ? 
my code like this :

```
$.each(data, function(key,row){
     if (row.section) {
         $.each(row.section, function(key, val){
             $('.select-section').append("<option value='"+val.id+"'>"+val.name+"</option>");
         });
     }else{
         $('.select-section').html("<option value='-'>-</option>");
     }
});
```

but my when i have an object like that above, the results is just replace the `section option value` with `else` condition (-)

i create this because sometimes an Object doesn't have a section key, so i create a default option when the `section` key is unavailable

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Maybe try ```if (Object.keys(row.section)[0] === "section")```

Comment: @Webbanditten my purpose is find the `row` have an object key section or not, but your answer is just check the section key value is section or not.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed two things in your **JS** code:

1. `if (key=="section")` instead of `if (row.section)` to check if the `key` is `section` or not;
2. `$('.select-section').append` instead of `$('.select-section').html` cause whatever you could append the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function will replace the whole html inside the `select` tag to `<option value='-'>-</option>`, then you'll never have other option then this one.

Please check this demo for a better understanding:

```js
var object={
    section : {
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'foo'}
    },

    unit : {
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'bar'},
    1 : {id : 2, name: 'bar2'}
    }
    };
    
    $.each(object, function(key,row){
 
     if (key=="section") {
         $.each(row, function(key, val){
         var opt="<option value='"+val.id+"'>"+val.name+"</option>";
             $(".select-section").append(opt);
         });
     }else{
         $('.select-section').append("<option value='-'>-</option>");
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-section"></select>
```

This solution still not perfect because I believe that if you'll have another `key` that is not `section` the code above will append one more the selection tag with `-`;

```js
var object={
    section : {
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'foo'}
    },

    unit : {
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'bar'},
    1 : {id : 2, name: 'bar2'}
    },
     unit2 : {
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'bar'},
    1 : {id : 2, name: 'bar2'}
    }
    };
    
    $.each(object, function(key,row){
 
     if (key=="section") {
         $.each(row, function(key, val){
         var opt="<option value='"+val.id+"'>"+val.name+"</option>";
             $(".select-section").append(opt);
         });
     }else{
         $('.select-section').append("<option value='-'>-</option>");
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-section"></select>
```

So I suggest that you append the `select` tag at the beginning, then there is no need to check if the `key` is not `section`. Here is another and better demo :

```js
var object={
    section : {
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'foo'}
    },

    unit : {
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'bar'},
    1 : {id : 2, name: 'bar2'}
    },
     unit2 : {
    0 : {id : 1, name: 'bar'},
    1 : {id : 2, name: 'bar2'}
    }
    
    };
     $('.select-section').append("<option value='-'>-</option>");//APPEND It HERE
    $.each(object, function(key,row){
 
     if (key=="section") {
         $.each(row, function(key, val){
         var opt="<option value='"+val.id+"'>"+val.name+"</option>";
             $(".select-section").append(opt);
         });
     }//NO NEED TO CHECK If It's NOT "SECTION"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-section"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do:

```
 var data = {
    section: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'foo'
    }],

    unit: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'bar'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'bar2'
    }]
  };

 if (data.section && data.section.length > 0) {
     $.each(data.section, function(key, val){
         $('.select-section').append("<option value='"+val.id+"'>"+val.name+"</option>");
     });
 } else {
     $('.select-section').html("<option value='-'>-</option>");
 }
```

plnkr: http://embed.plnkr.co/dxzbHir4x0RjQwQAfse1/

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the result is still same just like my code above, the option still showed like `else` condition` any ideas ?

Comment: @CodeBoam you dont need the  $.each(object, function(key,row){}) , updating ans